# Remove Border and Margin around iOS Charts in Swift

Tags: ios-charts

I am using [iOS Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) with Swift 3, and I can't figure out how to do a couple things:

1. I want to remove the margin around the chart. I know the chart goes edge-to-edge in my UI because if I change the chart's background color, it goes all the way to the edge. How do I remove the gap indicated by the red arrows below?
2. How do I remove the border around the whole graph (note the black arrow)? I already have `totalsGraph.drawBordersEnabled = false` and it doesn't work. Is there a different option for that?

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It is minOffset.

> /**
>     Sets the minimum offset (padding) around the chart, defaults to 10
>   */

You can change it as this:

```
chartView.minOffset = 0
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, setting the minOffset to zero will cause numbers on the right axis to be clipped.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I've been searching for this stupid offset for almost half an hour.

Answer (score 9):

that line is actually axis line.

To hide the all the lines, you can use

```
    totalsGraph.rightAxis.enabled = false
    totalsGraph.legend.enabled = false
    totalsGraph.leftAxis.enabled = false
    totalsGraph.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    totalsGraph.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    totalsGraph.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
```

I am looking for solution to remove margins as well. I will update my answer when I find it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the way to do it is like this:

```
chartView.xAxis.enabled = false
chartView.leftAxis.enabled = false
chartView.rightAxis.enabled = false
chartView.drawBordersEnabled = false
chartView.minOffset = 0
```