# Unable to remove extra margin in BarChart (Charts)

Tags: ios, objective-c, charts

One of my app using [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) library for drawing graphs.

Everything works fine but in `BarChartView` it's adding some default margin around the chart and I have done the below changes in the Chart property but still, it's not removing the margin around the graph.

I have also checked the same issue on this [Question thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39991754/remove-border-and-margin-around-ios-charts-in-swift) but no luck at all.

**Check below screenshot for margin issue:**

[image]

I have done the below changes for removing the margin around `BarChart`.

```
_barChartView.minOffset = 0;
    
_barChartView.xAxis.enabled = NO;
            
ChartYAxis *leftAxis = _barChartView.leftAxis;
leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = NO;
            
_barChartView.leftAxis.enabled = NO;
_barChartView.leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = NO;
            
_barChartView.rightAxis.enabled = NO;
_barChartView.rightAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = NO;
_barChartView.legend.enabled = NO;
```

But still, I am not able to remove the margin.

Also checked Charts Demo app has the same issue while changing data from the slider.

**Check Below screenshot from Chart Demo App:**

[image]

Any help or hint appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

Hello I have checked in the demo of Charts library which you have provided.

Where i have added below code and it's work, check the screenshot below.

**BarChartViewController.h**
 Add this code on line number : 115

```
_chartView.minOffset = 0;

_chartView.xAxis.enabled = NO;

_chartView.leftAxis.enabled = NO;
_chartView.leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = NO;

_chartView.rightAxis.enabled = NO;
_chartView.rightAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = NO;
_chartView.legend.enabled = NO;
```

[image]

[image]

let me know for more.

Here is the output of my simulator with blue background.

[image]

Comment: Yes I have checked on first look its working as expected now check slider value you can get that margin back on graph. That is the problem in BarChart.

Comment: check added screen shot of Demo app of chart same problem in that demo also.

Comment: I have change the value of Slider but works perfectly no margin there, which XCode version and which iOS version simulator your are using.

Comment: Have you set Background color of chart ? if not set this `_chartView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];` and check.

Comment: By the way I am using latest Xcode 8.3 and iOS 10.2 :)

Comment: Still I am getting extra space at bottom of the chart I have set above property in my chart and in Demo code also but not working at all.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but just for anyone who stumbles upon the question

This solved it for me

```
barChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0
barChartView.rightAxis.axisMinimum = 0
```